# How to tell boss that we need a test plan and to ensure developers use the QA process?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I just got a Warning letter for poor performance

I joined a new company as an Associate QA engineer and almost 70% of the developers are juniors and there are no project managers and business analysts. Every time the client decides on the release date and clients directly contact developers (for more than 5 years this how they have managed projects).

And developers release on time with lots of bug without basic tests. I send lots of emails regarding this but no one replies after 4 months I got a warning letter its mention

1. not build any QA progress
2. client complains
3. not tested any function

Actually all records are in gitlab and with out checking gitlab they issued a warning letter. How to tell my boss it's not my fault team leads don't care anything warn team leads

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're saying that your'e being blamed for poor testing when the developers simply bypassed QA and you never got to test it?

Comment: yep but i test and add bugs in gitlab

Comment: they release on time but client check few days after in that gap i test

Comment: So you logged bugs and it got released with bugs that you found?

Comment: _"they release on time but client check few days after in that gap i test "_ So, instead of QA being in the release pipeline, it's a parallel process? That's confusing.

Comment: yep and i try to explain my boss he said do not pass ball

Comment: @SouravGhosh they don't care and dont know abut new requirement client expecting  some thing developers done something so client directly call boss

Comment: Can the current edit be approved (hopefully with many spelling / grammar correction)

Comment: @GHOST how frequent your releases? I.e. 5 times a day or once a month?

Comment: @AndreiROM I wouldn't jump to conclusions of low effort; OP's mistakes seem like the kind that occur due to low familiarity with the language rather than laziness.

Comment: @AndreiROM True, but oftentimes that is set to your native language and just mark everything in red when writing in English (or in my case the other way around)

Comment: @rasan076 - same in my case, but I somehow manage.

Comment: *Actually all records are in gitlab and with out checking gitlab they issued a warning letter.* This is dangerous because by the sounds of it they are assuming the delivery success is up to you they believe you are the PM make sure they understand what QA do and email everything

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yep im the only one and they mean progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you raise the issue to your supervisor or other management, you can maximize your chances of having a productive discussion by **being focused on potential solutions and avoiding blaming or complaining.**

**Develop a specific solution proposal and bring it to your manager.** Make it clear you believe the root cause of the issues being noticed by the client is a lack of a test plan and controls around QA. Offer a suggestion of what the test plan and QA controls should look like and who is responsible for being sure they are followed.

**Focusing on resolving the issues perceived by your client is probably the best way to convince your organization that the problem isn’t amongst the developers** and to address the warning letter. Avoid getting defensive, blaming others, or complaining about the current situation.

Best of luck with the situation. It sounds like it could take a long time to rescue the project and even longer to help your organization see what is really going on. Being persistent and cooperative in developing a solution will be highly valued and appreciated.

Comment: thank you but we have 7 seniors members more than 7+ experiences  but they act they are working but even they don't know how to fix simple CSS

Comment: So the issue *is* the developers? What is the message you’re looking to get across to your organization’s management?

Comment: need test plan and developers should pass QA process

Comment: Okay - apologies, I didn’t fully grasp your question. Thanks for the clarification. I’ve revised my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have it documented that your bugs were found, and ignored.  Don't be afraid to speak up.    If the boss doesn't accept it, you may need to go above his head.    Or, I don't mean to blame you in any way, but you need to more assertively put it back on him that QA is worthless if  bugs are ignored.    If you got a warning letter, I'd refuse to sign it, take it to HR, or take it to his boss.

Comment: thank you i try to tell what exactly happen but they said do not pass ball accept its your fault :(

Comment: @GHOST Are they saying it's your fault that devs didn't fix the bugs you found?

Comment: @DaveG dev didn't fix any bug i found

Comment: @GHOST does management blame YOU for development not fixing bugs?

Comment: @DaveG exactly with out check bug report they blame me

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you how this works at my reasonably organised place.

As a developer, I start with a set of tasks that should be achieved for the next release. My boss has decided when the release is, and when QA needs to start testing.

I do the tasks in reasonable quality. Shortly before the date WA should start, if there are tasks not done my boss and I decide what can be left out of the release, or if the release needs to be delayed.

When I have no tasks to do (because I’ve done everything or things were moved to the next release), QA starts. WA reports bugs which become tasks for me. While QA reports bugs, I fix bugs. QA closes or reopens the bugs I fixed. If we come too close to the release date, my boss and I decide which bugs can be fixed for the next release.

The important thing: Every bug QA finds turns into a task for the devs, and the product is released when all those tasks are performed or postponed.

Comment: my dev team cant be like you they work 2 hrs and other 6 hrs they watch movies or playing if boss came they start act like they are working hard  (most of time boss on in the office he went some where )